# android: how to get data from a link and read it

Tags: java, android, web-services

I am trying to read a .txt and .csv file that I have added to my Dropbox public folder. I was able to read the data and print it with java on my pc but when I want to read and print the same data on Android I get some problems and I am not sure what I am missing or doing wrong, here is my code (which is the same as the program I ran on my pc):

```
        try
        {
            URL dataLink = new URL(link);
            URLConnection dlc = dataLink.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dlc.getInputStream())); //error happening here
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                 System.out.println(inputLine);
            }

        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) 
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
```

Also here is the error that I get:

```
12-26 16:43:31.295: D/AndroidRuntime(4988): Shutting down VM
12-26 16:43:31.295: W/dalvikvm(4988): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41af5da0)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988): Process: com.src.readingdata, PID: 4988
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1166)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at com.src.readingdata.GetData.onClick(GetData.java:65)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4753)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19562)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
12-26 16:43:31.295: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And the permissions I added are INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Any help would be great thanks!

Also this is my first time posting here so sorry if I did not do something correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to perform network operation in separate thread. Android do not allow network operation in main thread to make good user experience.

Please check this guide:
http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Comment: Thanks man this helped me a lot and solved my problem! Another issue I have now is that when doInBackground is finished it wont call onPostExecute, I thought its suppose to automatically call onPostExecute when doInBackgorund is finished?